# Break can not be used out side of loop

Tags: java, break

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  outerTimer = new Timer() {
    @Override
    public void run() {        
      if(stopTimer) {
        cancel();
        break; // break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch
      }

     repeatLoop();
    }         
  };

  outerTimer.run();
  outerTimer.scheduleRepeating(tmptimerDuration);
}
```

In the above code I used break to break the loop when stoptimer is true but it throws an error

```
break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch
```

But I used this `break` *inside* of timer where timer inside of another for loop.

So why I am getting error?

Comment: The `break` is not actually inside the loop, it's in a completely separate function unrelated to the surrounding scope.

Comment: The code inside `run()` is not inside a loop. It is the code run when the timer fires. It is only being set up inside a loop.

Comment: You need to use `return`.

Comment: because you are inside of an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). you are not in the scope of the loop anymore and hence you are not able to use break;

Comment: I don't think this question should be downvoted. It's very clear and well written.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty not sure, I see no particular issue with it. I suspect there is sometimes a tendency to downvote a question because it is perceived as "obvious", forgetting that we have all made obvious mistakes whilst learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous classes become separate classes at compile time. The following code is roughly equivalent:

```
class ContainingClass {
  void myMethod() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      outerTimer = new MyAnonymousTimer();

      outerTimer.run();
      outerTimer.scheduleRepeating(tmptimerDuration);
    }
  }
}

class MyAnonymousTimer extends Timer {
  @Override
  public void run() {        
    if(stopTimer) {
      cancel();
      break; // break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch
    }

   repeatLoop();
  }         
}
```

(the name `MyAnonymousTimer` is not the actual name of the class; it is more like `ContainingClass$1`)

As such, the `break` isn't really in the loop; it is mere syntactic convenience that you can declare it inline with the loop.

You need to use `return`, like you would to stop execution of any other `void` method.

Comment: I think that `return` in this case is equivalent to `continue`, it won't break the loop.

Comment: @MarounMaroun well, no. But it wouldn't break the loop anyway if `stopTimer` is set to true after the loop has finished executing.

Comment: Now I'm actually not sure, will check :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `final boolean` variable (that *can* be accessed from the function), and set its value to `true` when you should break. Then, in the `for` loop, you simply check if the variable `true` and break.

Your code doesn't work because the `break` is not really inside the `for` loop, it's inside the anonymous function that's in another scope.

Answer (score 0):

You see that the "break" is inside the loop graphically but the "break" is inside a different scope indeed.
This way the break instruction is executed inside the inner scope (and notice that there's a new one for each iteration).

What does the repeatLoop do? Because I was thinking to a different solution but I have to know its behavior.